# JsonToken EndConstructor is not valid for closing JsonType Object when deserializing a realm class object

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, mvvm, realm

I'm trying to deserialize a realm object class from json but I get  'JsonToken EndConstructor is not valid for closing JsonType Object. Path '', line 7, position 26.' I'm not sure what exactly the error means

Below is the json that I'm trying to deserialize:

```
   {
    "_id": "600a8843d2a5c05244d93f96",
   "brand": "LG",
   "category_id": 1,
   "final_price": "R9,699.99",
   "image_url": "https://www.hirschs.co.za/media/catalog/product/cache/9c364865bfa4e33d9a4215a5e5b5540b/7/2/72982_8d51bdcf2782d2283e6d0fc1a5558ab5.jpg",
   "name": "LG 140cm (55/") 4K Smart UHD TV - 55UN7100PVA",
    "regular_price": "",
    "sku": "72982",
    "special_price": "",
    "store_logo": "https://www.hirschs.co.za/media/logo/websites/1/Logo_2.png",
     "store_name": "Hirschs",
    "updated_on": "2021-01-22 10:09:39",
    "url": "https://www.hirschs.co.za/lg-140cm-55-4k-smart-uhd-tv-55un7100pva"
  }
```

Here is where I serialize my data:

```
  async void OnItemSelected(product item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        var model = await ProductService.GetProduct(item.Id);
        JObject jobj = JObject.FromObject(model);
        string jsonStrObj = jobj.ToString();

       
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ProductModel)}={jsonStrObj}");


    }
```

Here is where i Deserialize my data:

```
     public void LoadItemId(string p)
      {
        try
        {
           
            Debug.WriteLine("Name:" + p);
            var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<product>(p,new ObjectIdConverter());
           
            Debug.WriteLine("Name:" + product.Name);
            ProductName = product.Name;
            Url = product.Url;
            ImageUrl = product.ImageUrl;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
        }
    }
```

here is my converter class:

```
 public class ObjectIdConverter : JsonConverter
{
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());

    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return new ObjectId(token.ToObject<string>());
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ObjectId).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

Comment: the double quote embedded here `(55/")` should be preceded by a backslash to escape it.  Otherwise it's not valid json